# Move construction of type with user defined constructor accepting template type argument instantiated with an incompleted type

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, move-semantics

Trying to understand why does this code doesn`t compile with gcc and clang but compiles wth msvc.

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGISdKuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEegAOqAqETgwe3r7%2B0onJjgIhYZEsMXFctpj2eQxCBEzEBOk%2BfgHllak1dQQFEdGxegq19Y2ZLQOd3UUlEgCUtqhexMjsHAD0KwDUACoAnvGY69vzxOtoWOsIsZik6yTrtKhM6OuG65iqrPH0AHQmGgCC5gAzKFkN4ziZAW4CLtMAB9AjEJiEBQQ7C/AH/UFMBQKdYASQYaBYn0wBEwEKs/3RZOJBjJ6whbixOK2qPRA2IXgcW0wtKYZKeJgA7JS/utxVt1gQKejhQARGVU/4crkEHkDBki9ES16qT54ZCEdUECBoBgaza8z78zDoRkEokksmohlmABs00VAKFCsBovRoTVLCRDAgnqpWv%2BOrGjmQsOxSnqEAG6BAIDwClhLFQADc4WaVQ48FF6LCc4zLQNUddzGZwqgg7n9gWEari/Ra56/bKfRxZrROABWXh%2BDhaUioThuazWdYKI5LV2AnikAiaPuzADWIDMAE4voChULB1wuBpBwAOMwaMxcQf6TiSEfriecXgKEAaVfr2ZwWAwRAUFQYk6FichKEdUC4mALhATMUgsBzA1MAANTwTAAHcAHk9lHFcaFoMliA/CAohfKJQjqbZOBXCjmGIbYsKibRMAcGjeCJNhBCwhhaGosdeCwKIvGANwxFoD9uEE3lDGAcQBIQvBiFYxw80k8c3lYrwyXY8hBAqF9aGLREGI8LAXwRPAWHY2YqAMYAFDQzCcMYXT%2BEEEQxHYKQZEERQVHUBTdDKAwjBQGdLH0YsP0gWZUHiKpJIAWhTCE5VMSxrDMQFeCbYhiDwLAYrDVoVNSFwGHcTwmj0YJQh6Yo%2BjKHIUgEYY/GapJWoYCZelKUqiwEDohmqzIyjsMqhsGLp6smJrbGm9r%2Bmm3rGtKWZ5wWJYZgfDhh1IUdx0nDh1lUC83SSt1JHWYBkGQdZYK%2BMx1ggXBCFuIEuGmXg1wE6Ytx3e8Bw4J9SGsy8vi4MxsrdMxzt3LhdwvQFzwOl9jvfT9vz%2B0g/0A%2BYCHibTwNNYD4ig8JWGWM6Lqum67oewEnt4W13oK1Mync4RRHEHyuf8tQX2C0gMMReIf12/bDtyzgsO0om1VQKhTvOy7rtu%2B7HueiAPBA%2Bhjk%2B77sa0f7SAuR4%2BhK4HQesyQuC%2BC8jzdQ9YI0C8NC4N1d3vaXXw4TGv1%2Bk2AfdL5B0HXcNA0AJYdvaGhV2nK0YUjHjb7XGALxiAkEg/WSdzvosSMT2o4QzAkKWJzsNwty6CIkiyIUuiqN05uGKYli2Kk0hOMYAgeL4l8hJEsTaAk3SsGDIx5PHfBlKLNSX005BtOWFdAwMhSjKiEztjM5Zx0s6ypNs%2BzHPQ6vXO7rnPN56R%2BaUQWgp3fRZPCzLIu34q4oS1JktSwE6UIoWDMFEXKeZ8qFUwN/AaVQKpVQyB1UgdVCh9QSF1KoS1Oq5FSKtKY40KiTWqItUaSCJqDWIeMWaaDxokMQctKhqC1o7U2osby/YhzPhTpwFWtNrpF2AA9N0XwNAiJem9IgBtspfR%2Bj%2BEOQNHy8HBkKMOu5JC7kBG6IUbtzoaCFG6ZOR03y2CxkHdOWckAEwVvnMmFMqacBpmrE4oVBGexESIlm%2BBJGFT0DfHm3l76yAFoFccuh4KiyYOLHGwMpbo1lvLbSNxlaOLpgIoR7iNAvV1uTfWS4zBGzMabc2WA4hW0UWDfwZgviSHPBoZ2e5TyAl3GYaQvtU4fkDnI0g25bxhy9gjIU7s4JR0BJIBOwMk5tOMYUjO8ALFAT1mBCgpNFlxBzMgeI8QyyI1hHSaBBBYSqCumXCuqEL4uTwrwAi9dKCN3HG3fitFKLt2YipXSvduK8X4rPTAwlRLiUkiuSeskZ6CSUmVReCll6r10hvYG45t6733hZAqx8eCnyYA5KuFy3KyFvgE3y8hH4hJ0CAQEr8woZSsJ/aK8Af6JU4CsFM79qUWD2QMcBsR2bQLpbA8qEBXBYOQZVPB80WqYNIegnB%2BRqHMIIW0KanQhXkKqMNGaTD8ELSVZK2hjCGr4I2gudhksuFGJOkc66LAFDrPWDmRGXx2Vqlel4j60iCldJ6QokGSiQCDmEXBBGsFmk1MHHU8lUz/YmM6TjeZVjibLILsQSmbAHF0ytTau1%2B5HWeLZj4zmeL/ESECX5YlQsyUizFhLGJpqZYcDloTRJStTpputfdTNDqbQah1rY3JQJATur%2BrMYplsOHeoqZIJmWidFuj0RHdRh5DG1oDmnU2PSqnzr9W6LRzsLyDjMIOclEya1%2B1kYO3aZhj2p0KbMCByRnCSCAA%3D%3D%3D)

```
#include <type_traits>

class Incomplete;

template <class T>
struct Templated {
    T t;
};

struct Test {
    explicit Test(const Templated<Incomplete> &);
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_move_constructible_v<Test>, "Not move constructible");
}
```

GCC error:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'struct Templated<Incomplete>':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc- 
13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/type_traits:3257:7:   required from 
'constexpr const bool std::is_move_constructible_v<Test>'
<source>:18:24:   required from here
<source>:9:7: error: 'Templated<T>::t' has incomplete type
    9 |     T t;
      |       ^
<source>:5:7: note: forward declaration of 'class Incomplete'
    5 | class Incomplete;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

Clang error is conceptually same.

If one removes `const` specifier or constructor itself code will compile. Why does it work like this though constructor shouldn`t be used at all?

Comment: How can the compiler know that the constructor isn't the one to use, without instantiating the parameter type?

Comment: @BoP as far as i understand i would say that the type has already been instantiated on a function declaration so it can be used in function lookup. Its absolutely legal to use cv references to incomplete types as i did but error message looks like the compiler tries to evaluate user-defined constructor though it has to be omitted because of the presence of implicitly defined move constructor